# Retreiving each record in a table with its no of occurances

Tags: sql-server-2008

My table is given here...

```
Appear   Back_Color  Fore_Color

simple    White         Black
simple    white         Black
medium    Gray          Black
medium    Gray          Black
```

Now I want to retrieve  all the records with its no of occurance..

ie, The Result should be like this....

```
Appear   Back_Color  Fore_Color   count

simple    White         Black      2
medium    Gray          Black      2
```

what code can be used here?

Thanks and regards ,
 Nijisha K C

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT Appear, Back_Color, Fore_Color, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY Appear, Back_Color, Fore_Color
```

**Update**

Consider the test data that you have supplied:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Appear VARCHAR(10),Back_Color VARCHAR(10),
                   Fore_Color VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
('simple','White','Black'),
('simple','white','Black'),
('medium','Gray','Black'),
('medium','Gray','Black')
```

With this query:

```
SELECT Appear, Back_Color, Fore_Color, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM @tbl 
GROUP BY Appear, Back_Color, Fore_Color
```

The output is like this:

```
Appear  Back_Color Fore_Color count
medium  Gray       Black      2
simple  White      Black      2
```

Like you expected

Comment: I tried this. But Count is 1 for the repeating records